# Odds ratio terminology

Tags: terminology, odds-ratio

Suppose you have two groups $A$ and $B$ and you want to find the odds ratio of some outcome. How do you denote this odds ratio? Is it just $OR(\text{A} \ \text{and} \ B)$?

Comment: I think if your context is written clear enough, especially in the reference level that you defined, you can just use OR. Readers can understand the odds ratio is for A versus B.

Comment: Did you browse some of the related [questions and answers](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/odds-ratio)? Presenting results depends on whether you compute OR from a two-way table or a regression model, but usually @cchien's recommendation works well in practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen in some textbooks: $OR_{A/B}$